# Adding an activity: cannot resolve method 'findViewByID(int)'

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I'm following the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html and have done everything exactly as instructed in this and all preceding tutorials under "Building Your First App" in Android Studio v. 1.1.0.

My code in MyActivity.java:

```
package com.embeddedspring2015.jstrickling.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.embeddedspring2015.jstrickling.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    // Called when the user clicks the Send button
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

When I try to run the app, I get the error "cannot find symbol method findViewByID(int)"

All of the other files are untouched after being created by Android Studio or changed as directed by the tutorial. I have searched for anyone else who encountered this but nobody seems to have asked about this exact issue.

Comment: the method is `findViewById`, note  the lowercase **d** at the end

Answer (score 4):

When writing code realize that it is case sensative.  So when you write findViewByID it is not the same as findViewById.

The correct usage would be

`EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);`

Comment: In Android Studio you can use the command CTRL + SPACE to get the methods and fields avaliables.